# can't access CUPS interface

Tags: debian, cups

On attempt to access cups user interface at localhost:631/admin (or others) firefox gives "unable to connect". When i'm launching netstat i see no cups demon listening to port 631. Please help me to determine the problem.

Also here are errors from /var/logs/cups/error.log:

```
W [22/Jul/2016:12:23:28 +0300] Duplicate listen address "/var/run/cups/cups.sock" ignored.
E [22/Jul/2016:12:23:28 +0300] Unknown directive JobPrivateAccess on line 84 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [22/Jul/2016:12:23:28 +0300] Unknown directive JobPrivateValues on line 85 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [22/Jul/2016:12:23:28 +0300] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateAccess on line 86 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [22/Jul/2016:12:23:28 +0300] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateValues on line 87 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [22/Jul/2016:12:23:28 +0300] MF3010: File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca" not available: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and I was able to solve it by renaming `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` to `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf.busted`, and then running `dpkg-reconfigure cups-daemon`, which recreates `cupsd.conf` from scratch.

I have no idea what the cause of the problem was, and the freshly generated `cupsd.conf` bears no resemblance to the old file, so that doesn't help any.  But hopefully this will at least get some people unstuck.

Comment: This worked for me when I ran into a similar issue on Debian 12. I hadn't tried to print anything for some time, so I think my issue may have been a result of upgrading from Debian 11 to 12.